# Asymmetric coefficient in regression

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, regression-coefficients

When performing regression to estimate coefficients, the interpretation of the coefficients is symmetric, this means that for both positive and negative effect, the magnitude is the same.

For considering asymetric coefficients in a multivariate approach in regression tasks, which will be the best approach?

At the moment I know the NARDL approach but it is not in python.

For an example the following paper is applying NARDL technique: [see paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360544221011828)

For asymmetric coefficient interpretation the same paper states:

> An increase in energy prices have a higher and long-lasting effect on food prices than a decrease.

This basically implies that in regression, when havinng the following formula as an example:

```
Demand = interceipt + beta_price * price
```

Beta_price when estimated with OLS, a symmetric coefficient is computed so when having a value, the effect is the same in both directions. However, in lot of cases to increase the price has not the same effect than decrease.

[An example of the coefficients from the report of NARDL model](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jemiluyi-Olayemi/publication/330602914/figure/tbl4/AS:718804929744896@1548387858074/NARDL-Estimation-results.png)

So, I wonder if there is any trick to perform this in a classic regression framework.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "asymmetric coefficient" and what "approach" refers to.  Are you perhaps trying to ask how to perform regression with an asymmetric loss function, as in [quantile regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantile+regression+loss)

Comment: I don't see what NARDL (Nonlinear Cointegrating Autoregressive Distributed Lag) models have to do with this, either.

Comment: I added a paper where there is demonstrations of the methodology, so you can check how NARDL has lot to do with asymmetric coefficient in regression @jbowman.

Comment: @whuber I clarified the topic, hope its clear now. I thing is a very interesting topic, honestly not very spread on the community.  In case of asymmetric loss function in simple words is about training in a penalized way the algorithm but not about getting better estimates interpretation of estimates in the +/- direction in the variable effect.

Comment: you will just put different variables to your model, so you have one variable and one coefficient for price increase and another for price decrease, if I understood your problem. you can also use spline or polynomial regression

Comment: @rep_ho regarding your reponse, in case is clear for you, then you are ready to make a response with some extent info. Not sure how polynomial or spline will measure the different effect I mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two variables $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and you want
different slopes depending on $x_{1}>0$ or $x_{1}<0$, and same with
$x_{2}$. Then you can define
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{1}^{+} & = & 1[x_{1}>0]x_{1},\\
x_{1}^{-} & = & 1[x_{1}<0]x_{1},\\
x_{2}^{+} & = & 1[x_{2}>0]x_{2},\\
x_{2}^{-} & = & 1[x_{2}<0]x_{2},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $1[A]$ is the indicator function of $A$. The resulting regression
model is
$$
y\mid\boldsymbol{x}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}^{+}x_{1}^{+}+\beta_{1}^{-}x_{1}^{-}+\beta_{2}^{+}x_{2}^{+}+\beta_{2}^{-}x_{2}^{-}+\epsilon,
$$
which is easy to implement in Python or R. Now you get different coefficients depending on the sign of the covariates, which I believe is what you want. In your price example, you would let $x_1$ be the price difference: If the price decreases, the slope is $\beta_1^-$; if it increases it's $\beta_1^+$.

This sort of model is used in the computation of the [dual beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-beta), if you need an entry point to the literature.

Comment: Hi @Grassie, I understand that one way to do this is to include both [x1, x1 * (x1>0)] as regressors, then the first coefficient is the negative part, the second is the difference between positive and negative. i.e. interaction of x1 with a dummy variable for x1>0, or add [x1 * (x1<0). x1* (x1>0] as regressors to have the second coefficient be for the positive part directly. But What if we have only positive values? that means the effect is symmetric? because I saw results of dual-beta in datasets where is always X>0.